# How to determine why a file upload did not happen in `az fs upload` when there are no error messages?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have a number of `az storage fs file upload` commands - most of which are successful. For one however the file is not uploaded and there are no error messages.

```
az storage fs file upload --source ./black-violations.1.0.31.txt 
  --path whl/black-violations.1.0.31.txt -f ddexwhl 
  --overwrite --account-name my-account
```

What might be the way to see what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the below suggestion helps:

1. You can try running your `az storage fs file upload` command with `--debug` parameter. This will give the debug output with the response sent by the Azure Storage. You can analyze this to find if your request succeeded or failed.
2. You can enable the [diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/diagnostic-settings?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring&tabs=portal#create-diagnostic-settings) for your Azure Storage Account. Then analyze it by running [the query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/blob-storage-monitoring-scenarios#auditing-data-plane-operations) to identify any failures.
3. You can also check the [Storage Transaction metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/monitor-diagnose-and-troubleshoot-azure-storage/3-storage-metrics) and apply the splitting for the `API Name` and `ResponseType` to isolate the factors causing the failures. Hope this helps.

[image]